# QuickStart RESTful/data driven iOS app

Tags: ios, rest, restkit

Is there a resource where I can see some examples, quickstart or anything that'll allow me quick bootstrapping of an iOS app that's data driven using REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into ASIHTTPRequest.  It's probably the fastest way to get an iOS app getting a network protocol up and running.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ASIHTTPRequest, you can also check out [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) ([restkit.org](http://restkit.org/)). The author is active here and on the mailing list. The community is also quite helpful.